# Factoring algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I would like to know how to factor the following algebraic expressions:

1. $x^6-7x^3-8$
2. $4x^2+4-8x-12y-12xy$

Comment: Are you sure the second isn't actually $$4 x^2 + 4 - 8 x - 12 y + 12 x y=4 (x-1) (x+3 y-1)$$ or $$4 x^2-12 x y-8 x+12 y+4=4 (x-1) (x-3 y-1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x^6-7x^3-8$, set $t=x^3$. Then

$x^6-7x^3-8
\\=t^2-7t-8
\\=(t+1)(t-8)
\\=(x^3+1)(x^3-8)\\=(x + 1) (x^2 - x + 1)(x - 2) (x^2 + 2 x + 4)$

Comment: :-) fine answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

for 1) we get $$x^6-7x^3-8=(x-2) (x+1) \left(x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^2+2 x+4\right)$$ since $$2^6-7\cdot 2^3-8=0$$ we can do polynomial Long Division and since $$(-1)^6-7(-1)^3-8=0$$ we have also the solution $$x=-1$$
for 2) we have $$4(x^2+1-2x-3y-3xy)=4((x-1)^2-3y(1+x))$$

Comment: how do you arrive at that answer? is it possible for you to explain the process?

Comment: @user370026  You can try factors ($\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8$) of the constant term ($8$) to find the roots. Then do polynomial division.

Comment: After dividing by $x-2$ and $x+1$, one is left with $x^4 + x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2 x + 4$, good luck with factoring that. It's far more likely the "process" was like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E6-7x%5E3-8).

Answer (score 1):

What if I did it like this
       $$x^6-7x^3-8$$
The relationship between $x^6$ **and** $7x^3$ is $x^3$. So let $P=x^3$,thus
     $$P^2-7P-8=(P-8)(P+1).$$
But since $P=x^3$, the answer is $(x^3-8)(x^3+1)$

Comment: Great first answer. I edited you answer including some mathjax for nicer formulas. You can find a quick tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For 1), solve as a quadratic equation

$$(x^3)^2-7(x^3)-8=0=(x^3+1)(x^3-8).$$

Then you factor using the cubic roots of $-1$ and $2$, giving the linear factors $(x+1)(x-2)$ and two quadratic ones related to the complex conjugate roots.